# C# Placing "Return" into a function?

Tags: c#, control-flow

Is there any way to manipulate the program flow in C# from within a function?

I mean in C++ it was possible to place something like

```
#define Verify(x) if(x==null) return;
```

or

```
#define Verify(x) if(x==null) goto _exit;
```

into a macro and place Verify(x) anywhere into a function. In this example the macro could exit the function if some condition is met.
But in C#, you can place the verification into a function, the function might be inlined, but you always have to write something in the form of

```
if (Verify(x)) return;
```

. So the question is, is there any way besides exceptions, to manipulate the control flow of a calling function be a called function?

Comment: I severely dislike seeing control flow statements in macros or otherwise hidden. Don't do it. Exceptions are the way to go.

Comment: But exception have to much overhead.

Comment: What do you mean overhead? Exceptions are not used to control flow, but to indicate an error condition beyond which there is no way to execute a function. You don't throw exceptions just to move execution someplace else.

Comment: The idea is to test some condition at the beginning of a function and skip the rest of the function, if the conditions are not met. And I was wondering, if there is a shorter form than using `if() return;` construction.

Comment: I mean you can always use a delegate to a <T> to get this behavior right?

Comment: I'll give you references in answer below.

Comment: @Aaron, calling return from a delegate will exit the delegate but not the outer method, it won't do what the OP is asking.

Comment: Avoid using macros in C++. And if you have to use macros, then at least put parenthesis to avoid problem with complex expression. And also, it is always a good idea to write macro in a way that you are required to write a `;` at then end and that the macro works correctly inside a conditional statement. Assuming that you really want a macro, then it should be: `#define Verify(x) if((x) != nullptr) { } else ((void)0)` or something similar. If I were you, I would not write macros if you don't know why I put extra `()`, add an `else` and a final expression to force the use of a final `;`

Comment: Just use the c# way and return. This is how it's done in c#. And do NOT use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: Certainly no "safe" way to do it, hehe.

Comment: It is really a bad idea to hide return statement inside a macro. Expert C++ developer avoid using macros as much as possible and also avoid using `goto` and avoid names that start with an underscore. It would be a good idea for you to read **Meyers, Sutter and Dewhurst** books before you write you next line of code as you seems to write poor code.

Answer (score 3):

Usual way to protect from invalid conditions is to install a guard clause at the beginning of the method body. You can find full explanation about why do we need guard clauses and how to implement them in this article: [Why do We Need Guard Clauses?](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/why-do-we-need-guard-clauses)

I have also held a webinar on defensive coding and you can find recorded session here: [Advanced Defensive Coding Techniques](https://vimeo.com/channels/postsharpwebinars/200171139)